# ListView - onContextItemSelected manipulate the item instead of toString

Tags: android, listview

As you can see in the code below, when I LongClick on an item in ListView, i get a popup menu with option to manipulate the item (delete, update, etc).

the problem is that I use my function on item.toString instead the item itself.
How can i get the item itself, and put it as an argument in my functions?

onCreateContextMenu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, final View v, final ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.db_list_view) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    }
}
```

onContextItemSelected:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Object obj = lv.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    String nameToString = obj.toString();

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
        deletePlayerFromLongClick(nameToString);
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Update")) {
        updatePlayerFromLongClick(nameToString);
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Change Host/Guest")) {
        changeMembership(nameToString);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like:

```
yourAdapter.getItem(info.position);
```

or

```
((YourAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
```

or even simpler,

```
listOfItem.get(info.position);
```

Comment: can you be more specific? what is **my adapter** in this case?

Comment: @user8465954 you must have used adapter for your listview right? or you could try what Pavneet_Singh suggested.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yeah that could be more convenient & easy :)

Comment: i used **Object obj = lv.getAdapter().getItem(info.position);** and it worked!

Thanks!